# Extract first stage results from feols() IV regression for modelsummary()

Tags: r, modelsummary

I'd like to report the first and the second stage results from `feols()` IV regression using `modelsummary()`. I couldn't find a way (except running the first stage as a separate model).

I can display first and second stage results using `etable()`  like this:

```
library(fixest)
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)

# create a toy dataset
base <- iris
names(base) <- c("y", "x1", "x_endo_1", "x_inst_1", "fe")
base$x_inst_2 <- 0.2 * base$y + 0.2 * base$x_endo_1 + rnorm(150, sd = 0.5)
base$x_endo_2 <- 0.2 * base$y - 0.2 * base$x_inst_1 + rnorm(150, sd = 0.5)

# estimate an instrumental variable model
mod <- feols(y ~ x1 | fe | x_endo_1 + x_endo_2 ~ x_inst_1 + x_inst_2, base)

# First and second stage results
etable(mod, stage = 1:2)
```

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Umut

Comment: Not clear what you want to extract.  the output from `etable` is a `data.frame`

Comment: I'd like to use`modelsummary::modelsummary()` . `modelsummary(mod)` only prints the second stage. Even though I can access to firststage with `mod$iv_firststage`, I couldn't manage to feed those results to `modelsummary()`

Comment: Does this give you what you want? `modelsummary::modelsummary(mod$iv_first_stage)`. I get what appears to be the first stage model summary.

Comment: I think what doesn't work for me is to report first and second stage in the same table as in `modelsummary(mod, mod$iv_first_stage)`. It throws a "modelsummary could not extract goodness-of-fit statistics" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From fixest [documentation](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/feols.html#instrumental-variables):
[image]

To get both first and second stage, use `summary` with `stage = 1:2`. Then you can feed it to `modelsummary`:

```
modelsummary(summary(mod, stage = 1:2))
```

[image]

Comment: this is very cool

Comment: Is there a way to add the F-statistic of the instrument to this table?

Answer (score 1):

The first-stage IV regression model summary can be generated with:

```
modelsummary::modelsummary(mod$iv_first_stage)
```

[image: modelsummary]

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I tried that but didn't apparently :).